# 1st order non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a first order nonlinear differential equation. Can this ODE be solved for $x(z)$?
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}z}= ax^5+bx+c
$$

I have tried using a variable substitution but it did not work: any ideas?

This DE is found after solving a more complicated system of DEs; it was part of my physics research to find soliton solutions of a system of DEs. If a,b,c were known then I could use the partial fraction decomposition, but this is not the case. I was wondering if there is perhaps a physicist who has seen before such DEs.

I found out that it is Chini DE : $dy/dx=f(x)y^n-g(x)y+h(x)$. For n=2 it is Ricatti and for n=3 Abel DE.
If Chini Invariant does not depend on x then it can be solved since my f,g and h functions are constant. I need to find out how? There is a book of Kamke which will be helpful. Anyone knows the name of this textbook ? Thanks guys.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: So $x=x(z)$? It's a nonlinear equation and so asking for a 'general' solution is going to be tricky/not possible. Without a superposition principle, writing down an expression with the some number of unknowns that can describe every possible behavior of the solutions is mostly doomed before it even starts. In what context are you interested in solutions to this ODE? It is likely possible to find good approximate descriptions depending on what you need it for

Comment: If $c=0$ then you get a Bernouilli equation and the variable substitution $u=x^{-4}$ will do the trick. But I guess you already tried this substitution.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I see would be to rewrite
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac 1{ ax^5+bx+c}=\frac 1a\frac 1{(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)(x-r_5)}$$ where the $r_i$ are the roots of $ax^5+bx+c=0$. Then partial fraction decomposition to get
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac 1 a \sum_{i=1}^5 \frac {A_i}{x-r_i}$$ and integrating
$$z+C =\frac 1 a \sum_{i=1}^5 A_i\,\log(x-r_i)$$

Not very funny !

Comment: As an additional note regarding the Cauchy problem: your solution is correct if and only $x_0=x(z_0)\neq r_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,5$. Otherwise the equation has only one (stationary solution) $x(t)=r_i$ $i=1,\dots,5$.

Comment: Assuming of course 5 distinct roots exist and can actually be found. In the case of a root with multiplicity higher than 2, things would get very complicated.

Comment: @Anon. There as so many conditions to be satisfied ... ! You are totally correct, for sure. Cheers.